# WP menu is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Super newb question here, but my brian is not working tonight. I'm using a provided JS script on a wordpress site to make a single-page website menu scroll to the relevant section.

I have a menu with options 'Home' 'People' 'Info' 'Contact'

These links are structured like so: "http://sample.com/#home"

```
<!-- Navigation Menu -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation">
  <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li id="menu-item-15"   class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-15">
<a href="http://sample.com/#home">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-        item-51">
<a href="http://sample.com/#people">People</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-14">
 <a href="http://sample.com/#info">Info</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom  menu-item-54">
 <a href="http://sample.com/#contact">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>    
   </div>
<!-- End Navigation Menu -->
```

The JS follows below.

```
 //Navigation Scrolling
 $('#navigation a[href*=#]').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
&& location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
});
```

The problem: When clicking the menu-links, the page reloads and shows the relevant section.

I would like the menu items to scroll to the relevant section instead.

Thanks.

TL;DR Menu items reload page instead of scrolling to relevant section. JS above.

Comment: show the relevant html..

Answer (score 1):

Just prevent the default functionality of the anchor tag by using `event.preventDefault()`,

```
 $('#navigation a[href*=#]').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   //Rest of your code
```

Comment: @user2859646 Welcome to SO, if you think that this answer has helped in fixing your issue, then try to accept it. by clicking on the tick mark available with this answer.. And this is not a compulsion.. :)